# USA tax treatment of additional gain from an escrowed sale

Tags: income-tax, capital-gains-tax, escrow

In 2016, a privately-held company in which I owned shares was partially (irrelevant, I think) bought out by a private equity firm. We paid capital gains tax on the amount received in 2016 (minus that percentage of our basis).

A small amount was held back from the initial sale to cover contingencies. This fund, less whatever was taken out for unanticipated expenses after the takeover, was distributed in 201**7**. What is the correct treatment? An additional capital gain with zero basis?

This was not an installment sale, as the extra distribution could easily have been zero.

Comment: Was the privately-held company in the US? If so, I would have thought they would issue you with the appropriate information.

Comment: Yes, USA, maybe I should ask them.